# Import python requests with bazel new_http_archive rule

Tags: python, python-requests, bazel

I am getting "ImportError: No module named requests" error when trying to use new_http_archive rule to get requests.

WORKSPACE:

```
new_http_archive(
    name = "requests",
    urls = ["https://github.com/requests/requests/tarball/master/requests-requests-v2.18.4-90-g81b6341.tar.gz"],
    build_file_content = """
py_library(
    name = "srcs",
    srcs = glob(["requests/*.py"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
)"""
)
```

BUILD:

```
py_library(
    name = "foo",
    deps = ["@requests//:srcs"],
    srcs = glob(["foo.py",]),
)

py_test(
    name = "foo_test",
    srcs = glob(["foo_test.py",]),
    deps = glob([":foo",]),
)
```

If I use 'srcs = glob(["*"])' in the new_http_archive rule, I get all kinds of errors about missing .py files (which makes sence - there are all kinds of files in requests repository)

My question is, how to specify the build_file_content in such a way that it would give me a working requests library? 
(At this point I am not sure whether I am using right url, and right rule for the build_file_content)
I just want to be able to run my python code with Bazel and have Bazel manage providing the requests library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close. We can see the issue by looking inside the requests tar.gz :

```
$ tar -tf requests-requests-v2.18.4-90-g81b6341.tar.gz
...
requests-requests-81b6341/requests/adapters.py
requests-requests-81b6341/requests/api.py
requests-requests-81b6341/requests/auth.py
requests-requests-81b6341/requests/certs.py
requests-requests-81b6341/requests/compat.py
requests-requests-81b6341/requests/cookies.py
...
```

So all of the files are inside of a directory called requests-requests-81b6341. Since your BUILD file has `glob(["requests/*.py"])` in it, this matches nothing. To solve this, you can use the `strip_prefix` attribute of the `new_http_archive` rule:

```
new_http_archive(
    name = "requests",
    urls = ["https://github.com/requests/requests/tarball/master/requests-requests-v2.18.4-90-g81b6341.tar.gz"],
    strip_prefix = "requests-requests-81b6341",
    build_file_content = """
py_library(
    name = "srcs",
    srcs = glob(["requests/*.py"]),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"]
)"""
)
```